# Default tolerance for float columns in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose I have two DataFrames and do something like
`df1.except(df2)`.  If one of the columns in the DataFrame is a float/double, what tolerance (if any) will be used for equality testing by default?

My observation is that if I do something like

```
val df1 = spark.sql("select cast(1.0001 as float) as foo")
val df2 = spark.sql("select cast(1.0002 - 0.0001 as float) as foo")
val df3 = spark.sql("select cast(1.0002 as float) as foo")
```

then `df1.except(df2)` and `df2.except(df3)` act as might be naively expected.

Note that I'm not asking for how to fix or avoid any problems this might create; I'm only asking for what *will* happen, if you do not take steps to acknowledge the issues with floating point by nature being inexact.

Comment: Maybe [this code comment](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f5d5422a4f87f69514d95f80f5f3db8246d61256/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2101) can give a hint: _Equality checking is performed directly on the encoded representation of the data_

Comment: It's a start - first I'd need to understand how the data (Dataframe = Dataset[Row]) is actually encoded though.